# How to make icon in sherlock actionbar when clicked open slidemenu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I'm using this library for a sliding menu: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu. How can I set a clickable icon in Sherlockactionbar?

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar action;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SlidingMenu sm =  new SlidingMenu(this);
        sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

        action = getSupportActionBar();
        action.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        action.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        action.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        action.setIcon(R.drawable.menu);         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set onClick listener.

```
sm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Comment: im want when click icon in actionbar opend slidmenu ,dont want clicked to slidmenu @Shoeb Ahmed Siddique